# I want to create a work flow for a user logged in from particular region then Netsuite should pick up that region Invoice form

Tags: workflow, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to create a workflow please see below example
For Instance, a user assigned to two regions i.e., Australia and Newzealand then user need to invoice Australian sales order then netsuite should pick up the AU-Invoice form.
Could you please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Each Role can have a "Preferred Form" for each Transaction type, so for all of your Australian Roles, you would set the AU-Sales Order form as Preferred. To do this, go into the customization of the AU-Sales Order form and look at the "Roles" tab. Mark the form as Preferred for all applicable Roles.

Next check out the "Linked Forms" tab; this tab lets you define the flow of forms that will be used automatically as the transaction progresses.

Repeat for any of the other regions you have.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out eric. But my user is assigned two regions. Is there any way can I put a workflow rule to trigger the specific region if the user is invoicing for that region. Could you please help me out to sort the issue.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out eric. But my user is assigned to two regions. Is there any way for me to put a workflow rule to trigger the invoice form of the particular region that user is logged into.

Comment: How do you determine which region they're logged in to?

Comment: Hi eric, system automatically does it. I believe it does based on subsidiary. Could you please help me out figure it out?

Comment: Thank you Eric. I have fixed this issue. Thank you so much for your time. Now I have another issue

Comment: I want to create a workflow which should trigger the subsidiary invoice form when i try to invoice a order.

Comment: For instance, i have AU-AUD, AU-USD, NZ-NZD, NZ- USD, then if a reseller is from AU, then I need a workflow to pick the AU invoice form. Could you please help me out to sort this issue